# How to get current selected row from ListView in Qt with C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to delete row in my database, through Qt ListView. 
So in GUI window I have listView with some data. User select one row and after clicking 'delete button', the row is deleting from ListView and database.
I have problem with getting the number of the row which the user selected. The program returning me value  -1

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonUsunWydatek_clicked()
{
    connectionOpen(); // Open connection to the DB
    QSqlQueryModel model; 

    int index = ui->listView_Wydatki->currentIndex().row(); //want to get current selected row by the user

    int id = model.record(index).value("id").toInt(); //here I collect specific ID from Database

    //here I check if it get well
    qDebug() << "ID: " << id;
    qDebug() << "Index: " << index;

    model.setQuery("DELETE FROM wydatki WHERE id = "id" "); //how to properly put id variable here?

    connectionClose(); //closing connection with DB 
}
```

@John Zwinck my question is not the same like that you linked into. I have problem with getting the index of the selected row. And in that answer you posted, the user want to know how to get items, that's not the same in my opinion. But I will analyse it, maybe I will invent something helpful

Comment: The id is the right one?

Comment: I don't know, beacuase I can't even properly reach the index value from ListView, so I have no option to check. But it should be right one

Comment: Your question though is a bit confusing with the `//how to properly put id variable here?` comment in the code. Also while the duplicate may be not the best one for a person with some lacking Qt knowledge. The approach to use `selectionModel` and `selectedIndexes` should help you along.

Comment: @Hayt With `id` I mean, how to properly insert id value in SQL statement. But this is least important. And what do you mean through 'duplication'? I am trying to use `selectionMode` and `selectedIndexes` but they returned QModelIndexList and I don't know what to do with this